# cant have my php code executed

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to make an html form ....there is no proplem in the html code but..
when i refer the form action tag to my learnphp.php file and click submit  it shows the whole code
like this pic please help... [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgVXQ.jpg
i will be very happy if you solved this for me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not putting the php file in right folder. localhost file should be on c:xampp/htdocs  in xampp when running php file.

you should run it by localhost::folder_name/php.php

Comment: thank you so much i didn't know that i should install xampp to code php i will install it right now and get back to you .....(i'm a beginner btw)

Comment: thank you so much for your help ......but one more question please .... when i try to run apache in xampp it says api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing and i've downloaded this file and same shit happens every time

Answer (score 0):

does your xampp or wamp on ? check it

Comment: i didn't install xampp but i'm installing it right now....can you tell me what is xampp is made for.....(thank you so much for your helpful comment

Comment: my xampp is on and i put the php file in htdocs and the same proplem happens